# Can excel return the dynamic address of a specific cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to work out if I can get the address of a specific cell (X) returned as a value (e.g **B7**), but in such a way that, should (X) subsequently be moved (e.g. **B7 moves to M7**), the correct, current address (M7) will be returned?  It happens that X will be on a separate sheet in the same file.

The value of cell X will change, so I can't lookup using the value.

Thanks

Comment: You will need something that you can use as an anchor.  Is there a cell somewhere around it that will always have a unique value that is static?

Comment: You may attach a meaningless formula to the cell and search for it. This needs VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Enter these in cell A1 and below

A1: `=CELL("address";A3)`
A2: `=INDIRECT(A1)`
A3: `Testing`

Now, cell A2 should show "Testing" (the content of A3).

Grab A3, move it - the "link" in A1 should move with it.
A2 should still display the same copy of the referenced cell.

***Note: Having many links like this will slow down you calculations notably.***

Comment: Wish I could upvote more than once

Comment: Thanks.  This is close to being what I need, but this gives me the result "Testing", no matter where I move A2.  I want the contents of A2 to say "A3", or "B7", or any other other cell reference depending on where A2 has been moved.

Comment: So? What you're looking for is there already, in A1.